# How to make urxvt and emacs display fonts the same way?

Tags: emacs, fonts, arch-linux, urxvt

Here's an image of emacs (left) and urxvt (right) displaying contents of the same file. Note how urxvt characters are shorter, wider, and (to me) not as pleasing to the eye.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Lza.png]

On some systems (GuixSD, last I checked), they display fonts exactly the same out of the box. On others, however, such as Arch, they do not. I'm currently on Arch.

How can I make them display fonts the same way? Ideally closer to how emacs does it.

Comment: Installing infinality helps, but the terminal font is still wider and shorter.